# Is there a way to periodically record the files being opened in emacs?

Tags: files

Sometimes my ubuntu freezes, and I am using Emacs that has many files opened inside it. I have to reboot Ubuntu, and lose the track of what files I have opened.

Is there a way to periodically record the files being opened in Emacs (maybe by more than one Emacs process), and to allow me to read the record of opened files later for example after rebooting OS?

Btw, I found that `sudo lsof -u t  |   grep emacs` only gives the directory where each emacs process was started, not the files being opened in Emacs. Does anyone know why?

Comment: re the `lsof`, I think it's because emacs doesn't keep the files open, it just reads it into a buffer and then closes the file handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Desktop mode for this, see [(emacs) Saving Emacs Sessions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Saving-Emacs-Sessions.html):

> Use the desktop library to save the state of Emacs from one session to
>   another. Once you save the Emacs desktop—the buffers, their file
>   names, major modes, buffer positions, and so on—then subsequent Emacs
>   sessions reload the saved desktop.
>
> [...]
>
> When `desktop-save-mode` is active and the desktop file exists, Emacs
>   auto-saves it every `desktop-auto-save-timeout` seconds, if that is
>   non-nil and non-zero.

Comment: Thanks. Does your way help to reopen files after rebooting Ubuntu?

Comment: @Tim Yes, the desktop file is a persistent file on disk, so it survives across reboots.

Answer (score 1):

Create an idle-timer whose function maps over `buffer-list` gathering the `buffer-file-name`s and writing them to a file.

Turn on that timer in each Emacs session.
You probably don't want to run the timer function *too* often.

Keep track of the file names written, so you can avoid rewriting the same set of names to disk.  (For that, make sure you check for set, not list, equality.)

Comment: Thanks, but I am not familiar with elisp... and I don't know how to do what you said. I'd appreciate If you could provide specific code and steps.

Comment: It's not hard. But I'll leave that to someone else's answer. If no one answers with such code then I'll post something later, when I get a moment. But I expect that you'll see a good answer soon from someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Install [supersave](https://github.com/bbatsov/super-save) and enable idle saving, e.g.:

```
(use-package super-save
  :ensure t
  :init (setq super-save-auto-save-when-idle t)
  :config (super-save-mode +1))
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit about what it does? Does it save all file-visiting buffers, for example?

Comment: My answer is off topic. The correct answer is the desktop-mode. Supersafe saves all file visiting buffers every time a buffer loses focus and can be made to save when emacs is idle, but it does not keep a list of files.

Comment: If you think your answer is helpful in the context of this question then please consider incorporating some of your comment into the answer. If you think it is not helpful here, please consider deleting the answer. Thx.